# Value resetting to 'null' when page is refreshed. Receiving error "Cannot read property 'email' of null". Is there any way to prevent this?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

I am attempting to display the username of a profile in a social media app. I am using Firestore and have a collection of 'users'. I have the database set up to where I search them by their email, not their ID. When I refresh the page, I receive the error "Cannot read property 'email' of null" on my line where I declare userDocKey.

Is there any way to keep the information stored when the page is refreshed?

```
const ProfileCard = (props) => {

    const [currentUsersName, setCurrentUsersName] = useState();

    const userDocKey = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;

    const getUser = async () => {
        try {
            const documentSnapshot = await db
            .collection('users')
            .doc(userDocKey)
            .get();

            const userData = documentSnapshot.data();
            setCurrentUsersName(userData);
           
        } catch {
            
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      getUser();
    }, [])

return (
  <p>{currentUsersName && currentUsersName?.name}</p>
);


};
```

For some reason I cannot post a picture of how my database is setup. But I have a collection of users populated with documents where the key is their email they signed up with. The variables inside each document are the users 'email','name', 'profileType', and 'timestamp'.

What I am attempting to do in my code is assign the constant userDocKey to the current user (signed in users) email that is stored in firebase's authentication.

From there I access the documents with the userDocKey. Since I assigned the authenticated email to the userDocKey variable, I am able to access the signed in users information that is stored in firestore.

Is there any way to prevent this error I am receiving from happening?

Comment: Hey, the error that is happening is because firebase is not initialized automatically when the page refreshes. You can add a validation to ensure that the current user exists to avoid the error like this: `const userDocKey = firebase.auth().currentUser?.email;`. And then set the `userDocKey` as a parameter in the `useEffect`. Then, when the user is logged in on the firebase auth method, the `userDocKey` will have the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

The loading of the `auth` data takes more time than your component needs to render and it can happen (most of the time) that `auth().currentUser` yould be `null`. To awoid that I would recommend to use the `onAuthStateChanged` listener:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    var uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

Either in that component or what I would recommend to create a react `Provider` that gives you the state of the `auth` trough the `Context`. This will also work with all Providers and you would have a single solution for all auth stata changes (also signout).